# GloVe Text Summarization returning stop word gibberish

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, summarization

I am trying to train a Keras test summarization model to generate a new headline for a news article that I can then compare to the published headline. I am training on GloVe 6B, then predicting against the article, which I have cleaned by removing tags, parsing, removing stop words, lemmatized, and then rejoined. My results tend to look like this:

Original Headline:  Ford Traveled To Maryland In August Despite Allegedly Fear Of Flying
Generated Headline:  opinion: the the the the to to

Article text after cleaning: Brett Kavanaugh accuser Christine Blasey Ford took polygraph test Maryland far home California despite alleged fear flying Documents released Wednesday polygraph test administered Ford Aug. 7 Hilton Hotel Linthicum Heights Maryland far Baltimore Washington International Airport A friend Kate DeVarney   Blasey Ford enjoy flying hard time place ’s escape route Christine Blasey Ford professor accusing Supreme Court nominee Brett Kavanaugh having sexually assaulted high school previously told friend alleged encounter 30 year ago lasting effect life Two longtime friend Ford ’s told CNN week previously described feeling uncomfortable struggling enclosed space escape route exit door suggested discomfort stemmed alleged encounter Kavanaugh This reason Ford enjoy flying DeVarney said airplane ultimate closed space away The fear flying   Ford able testify timely manner Senate Judiciary   In letter California Democratic Sen. Dianne Feinstein dated July 30 2018 Ford said vacation Mid Atlantic Aug. 7 day polygraph given Ford testify Senate 10 a.m. EST Thursday

Here is my training code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras_text_summarization.library.utility.plot_utils import plot_and_save_history
from keras_text_summarization.library.seq2seq import Seq2SeqGloVeSummarizer
from keras_text_summarization.library.applications.fake_news_loader import fit_text
import numpy as np

LOAD_EXISTING_WEIGHTS = False


def main():
    np.random.seed(42)
    data_dir_path = './data'
    very_large_data_dir_path = './very_large_data'
    report_dir_path = './reports'
    model_dir_path = './models'

    print('loading csv file ...')
    df = pd.read_csv("dcr Man_Cleaned.csv")

    print('extract configuration from input texts ...')
    Y = df.Title
    X = df['Joined']
    config = fit_text(X, Y)

    print('configuration extracted from input texts ...')

    summarizer = Seq2SeqGloVeSummarizer(config)
    summarizer.load_glove(very_large_data_dir_path)

    if LOAD_EXISTING_WEIGHTS:
        summarizer.load_weights(weight_file_path=Seq2SeqGloVeSummarizer.get_weight_file_path(model_dir_path=model_dir_path))

    Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    print('training size: ', len(Xtrain))
    print('testing size: ', len(Xtest))

    print('start fitting ...')
    history = summarizer.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, Xtest, Ytest, epochs=20, batch_size=16)

    history_plot_file_path = report_dir_path + '/' + Seq2SeqGloVeSummarizer.model_name + '-history.png'
    if LOAD_EXISTING_WEIGHTS:
        history_plot_file_path = report_dir_path + '/' + Seq2SeqGloVeSummarizer.model_name + '-history-v' + str(summarizer.version) + '.png'
    plot_and_save_history(history, summarizer.model_name, history_plot_file_path, metrics={'loss', 'acc'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a very broad question and there are a lot of things that can go wrong. The problem here is that your model is stuck in the classes due to several reasons:

1. Most probably you have an insufficient amount of data and the model is not able to learn from that so it just predicts the most probable output.
2. Your model is either too big or to small. If it's too big, it's not able to learn enough from the data to predict the correct words so it just predicts the most probable ones so that it minimizes the error. If it's too small, it doesn't have the capacity to learn such a complex structure as natural language.

Either way, you should try and add some layers, delete some layers, add some regularization, try roulette wheel approach to generate the next word based on words probability. Hope this helps :)